# Ordenar consulta mysql por numeros presentes em coluna varchar

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma tabela com uma coluna varchar e quero realizar um SELECT e ordenar o resultado pelos numeros presentes nessa coluna.

A tabela:

nome: moedas
colunas: id, nome, preco, catalogo

A coluna catalogo consiste em um VARHCAR(50), tendo por exemplo, os seguintes valores:
moeda 1 - 'CJ 0039';
moeda 2 - 'CJ 0025';
moeda 3 - 'CJ 0131.2';
moeda 4 - 'CJ 0206';

Quero ordenar o resultado assim:
moeda 2;
moeda 1;
moeda 3;
moeda 4;

Já tentei o seguinte select:

```
SELECT 
   id, 
   catalogo, 
preco FROM moedas 
order by ABS(CAST(catalogo AS UNSIGNED)) asc
```

Comment: Poderia mostrar o script de criação da sua tabela e o select que já tentou?

Comment: SELECT id, catalogo, preco
FROM moedas 
order by ABS(CAST(catalogo AS UNSIGNED)) asc

Comment: Se quer ordenar apenas pela parte numérica ?

Comment: Isso, pela parte numerica presente na coluna catalogo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Criei a tabela, inseri os dados e deu tudo certo por aqui.

Segue código:

```
SELECT
  id,
  nome,
  preco,
  catalogo
FROM moedas
  ORDER BY catalogo ASC
```

Saida do meu mysql:

```
2   |  moeda 2  |  45,66  | CJ 0025
1   |  moeda 1  |  99,55  | CJ 0039
3   |  moeda 3  |  44,55  | CJ 0131.2
4   |  moeda 4  |  55,44  | CJ 0206
```

Comment: Mais simples do que imaginado. Obrigado.

Answer (score -1):

Se todas as linhas forem no mesmo padrão de seu exemplo, e supondo que moeda x não faça parte do conteúdo do campo, tente:

```
SELECT * FROM sua_tabela 
ORDER BY (CASE catalogo WHEN 'CJ 0025' THEN 1 
                        WHEN 'CJ 0039' THEN 2
                        WHEN 'CJ 0131.2' THEN 3
                        WHEN 'CJ 0206' THEN 4) ASC;
```

Se quiser considerar apenas os números existentes dentro da string, eliminando qualquer caractere alfabético, use:

```
ORDER BY CAST(REGEXP_REPLACE(catalogo, '[[:alpha:]]', '') AS NUMERIC) ASC;
```

Obviamente supondo que seu exemplo tenha sido apenas mal escolhido, já que de acordo com ele bastaria ordenar pelo campo catalogo, coisa que não deve ocorrer na realidade para você postar tal pergunta.